With a current Jamaican Passport. Married a US citizen in Sept while B1/B2 active, now expired
I have a current Jamaican Passport & Drivers License. Have been dating and Married a US born citizen in Sept while B1/B2 active, now expired. We have been together for 19 months.
This is my 5th time to US, never not returned to Jamaica. Traveled here on work visa in past. No legal problems. Lawyer has filed paperwork and all immunization is complete.
Can I fly within the US?

So to clarify, you're saying your visa has expired and you're currently in the US illegally?

Whether your B visa is expired has no bearing on your immigration status.  What counts is the "admit until" date on your I-94 (or on your passport stamp, if you have one).  Is that the date that passed?  If so, did you file the paperwork before or after it passed?

When you say "Lawyer has filed paperwork" I assume that's for an adjustment of status to be a permanent resident on the basis of your marriage and that it was done within the deadlines for making such filings? In that case you are in the country legally, and will have no problems. But ask your lawyer - they will give you all the details in a definitive way.

I say "you will have no problems", but in about six weeks there is the spectre of "mass deportations" using the military, who are unlikely to be aware of the nuances of immigration law and the possibility they will just deport anybody not carrying the documents to prove they have permission to stay.

@lambshaanxy: "you're saying your visa has expired and you're currently in the US illegally?" First, visa expiration is just the last date on which one can enter the US with that visa, and has nothing to do with one's stay. It is perfectly normal to be admitted for and be staying legally for months or years after one's visa expired. Second, it sounds like they have a pending Adjustment of Status application, which would allow them to stay legally.

@phoog: "If so, did you file the paperwork before or after it passed?" That doesn't matter if they are doing Adjustment of Status in the Immediate Relative category (spouse, parent, or unmarried under-21 child of US citizen).

@user102008 doesn't it have a bearing on the accrual of unlawful presence?

@phoog: They do accrue unlawful presence in the period from when their I-94 expires until they file Adjustment of Status. But unlawful presence has no effect on their Adjustment of Status.

@user102008 thanks.  What about deportability, which is more relevant to this question?  I realize that someone with a pending AoS application wouldn't normally be deported even if out of status, but I recall that during the previous administration this was no longer taken for granted, and of course the incoming administration is expected to adopt policies at least as unfavorable to those who are out of status.

@phoog: Adjustment of Status can be filed in immigration court as relief from deportation. So if they were put into removal proceedings, I believe they could just file or renew their existing Adjustment of Status with the immigration judge, and then the immigration judge either adjudicates the Adjustment of Status, or closes the removal proceedings and let the person file it with USCIS.

There are no immigration checks within the US. Your immigration status is not a requirement for your ability to fly. Unless you bump into an ICE agent or a warrant is issued against you, no-one would care.
You do need a valid identification, either a valid unexpired passport, or a US issued driving license/id card (though you'll need a Real ID starting coming May, which given your immigration status you probably are ineligible for).
That said, if you have a lawyer - why don't you ask your lawyer.
